# Is the iTunes Library writable via COM?

Tags: c#, com-interop, itunes-sdk

I'm trying to increment playcounts via the iTunes COM API, and I'm getting this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : The track is not modifiable.

I haven't been able to find any documentation to help with this. Is the library writable? Is there a specific precondition to writability, such as a collection item being contained at a specific index in its collection (as opposed to iterating through an IEnumerable with LINQ filters)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can write to any track that belongs to a *file* (not URL) that is locally available (not only in iCloud) and writable. As-in: the actual file is writable.